Continuous map from $L^{p+1}(\Omega)$ to $L^\frac{p+1}{p}(\Omega)$
I am having trouble showing the following map is continuous:
Let $n\geq2$, $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain, and $1<p<2^*-1$, where $2^*=\frac{2n}{n-2}$ is the Sobolev conjugate of $2$. The map $\tau:L^{p+1}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^\frac{p+1}{p} (\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ is given by
$$u\mapsto |u|^{p-1}u.$$
I could show $\tau$ is bounded, however, I could not show it is continuous. Could someone tell me how I should approach this?
Thanks!

I would suggest approximation by smooth functions and difference = integral of derivative?

This operator is a specific variant of the Nemytskii Operator.
Here, one can think about using brute force (i.e. dominated convergence).
Let $u\in L^{p+1}(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$ and $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq L^{p+1}(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$ be a sequence that converges to $u$ in $ L^{p+1}(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$.
Then, every subsequence of $u_k$ has a subsequence (that we denote by $u_{n_k}$) that converges to $u$ pointwise a.e.. Most importantly, $\lvert u_{n_k} \rvert^{p-1}u_{n_k} \rightarrow \lvert u \rvert^{p-1}u$ pointwise a.e..
Moreover for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$
\big\lvert \lvert u_k \rvert^{p-1}u_k - \lvert u \rvert^{p-1}u \big \rvert^{\tfrac{p+1}{p}} ~\mathrm{d}x \leq 2^{\tfrac{1}{p}}\left( \big \lvert \lvert u_k\rvert^{p-1}u_k \big \rvert^{\tfrac{p+1}{p}}+  \big \lvert \lvert u\rvert^{p-1}u \big \rvert^{\tfrac{p+1}{p}}  \right) 
$$
Note that $$
2^{\tfrac{1}{p}}\left( \big \lvert \lvert u_{n_k}\rvert^{p-1}u_{n_k} \big \rvert^{\tfrac{p+1}{p}}+  \big \lvert \lvert u\rvert^{p-1}u \big \rvert^{\tfrac{p+1}{p}}  \right) \rightarrow 2^{\tfrac{1}{p}}\left( \big \lvert \lvert u\rvert^{p-1}u \big \rvert^{\tfrac{p+1}{p}}+  \big \lvert \lvert u\rvert^{p-1}u \big \rvert^{\tfrac{p+1}{p}}  \right)
$$
in $L^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$ and pointwise a.e. due to the assumed convergence of $u_k$ in $L^{p+1}(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$. Then, the generalized dominated convergence theorem (Evans, Gariepy - Measure Theory and fine properties of functions, Theorem 1.20) yields
$$
\int_{\Omega}\big\lvert \lvert u_{n_k} \rvert^{p-1}u_{n_k} - \lvert u \rvert^{p-1}u \big \rvert^{\tfrac{p+1}{p}} ~\mathrm{d}x \rightarrow 0.
$$
As the subsequence from which $u_{n_k}$ has been extracted was arbitrary, the above limit also holds for the general sequence $u_k$ which is your desired continuity.

When extracting the pointwise a.e. convergence, one can also directly obtain a corresponding dominating function (see Brezis book). This would simplify the proof.

Thank you for the nice hint, I‘ll later take a look at the book!
